# What is the way forward after this edit rejection?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I searched StackOverflow for an answer I needed, found it, ran into trouble applying it - part of the answer I didn't understand, part of it I had to create for my case, forcing me to research other bits of solution.

When I finally had success, I thought I should give back to the community and come back and make the answer more complete and clear.

But my edit was rejected:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9584796

... on the grounds that

`This edit was intended to address the author of the post`

No, it wasn't. Why would you say that?

`and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.`

Of course it's an edit. Adding three dumb lines of code to the 80 lines there, that actually do interesting things, is not a new answer; however, it is pretty hard to do with clarity in a comment...

**What is the peaceful, appropriate way of moving forward from here**? Should I really steal all that code and propose a new answer? It will be hard for future viewers to understand which version is better.

Comment: Correct or not, it's quite a few "major" changes to what is there. It would be best to create a separate answer and highlight the points you are trying to make. Referencing the other answer would be completely acceptable and you wouldn't/shouldn't need to copy all of the answer's code

Comment: We don't "steal" around here, content is licensed explicitly to allow derived works.  Simply follow the guidance and attribute the original poster appropriately.  A link to his post and a link to his profile.

Comment: The original 'community wiki' idea would seem to legitimize constructive improvements to someone else's answer; things that build, not rewrite. I don't think that answers should be immutable. Always insisting on copy-attribute-mod just feels messy to me.

Comment: *peaceful* ... wut

Comment: Your new function itself doesn't seem to do anything, except for passing in the project path, far from a 'necessary function' as per your comment. At best it's a matter of preference as to whether you want two methods instead of one - it's not objectively better. The rest of the changes seem to be superfluous and don't (IMO) make it any clearer to the reader. I would have rejected too, not because of the large amount of changes, but because it appears to have no improvement over the original.

Comment: @Rob: there is a tiny bit of additional value. The question asked for code, not manual typing, but the answer did not complete the information needed to make that code run automatically. It just assumed that people know how to. I'm not familiar with Access, so I didn't know how. The AutoExec macro is only one of the many ways available. You are right about the extra function being just a matter of preference. Maybe I'll just drop that and mention AutoExec in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Will: for a newbie in this site, like me, peacefulness isn't always obvious. These sites are not without negativity (they need to be tough to keep quality). Basically, I was at a point where I felt I could be going against the reviewers, or stealing from the other answer (I realize now that should not be a concern if done properly), or causing confusion to future viewers but multiplying almost similar answers - there seemed to be no good options. But the answers and comments here were useful to guide me.

Comment: I would like to apologize to the two people downvoting my question for maybe wasting their time. To me it was useful and a learning experience. Thanks to everyone involved.

Answer (score 5):

Many reviewers (myself included, although I did not review this particular edit) will use "attempt to reply" in cases where the edit is of a scope that it should really be an answer on its own with a link back to the original for attribution. That seems to be the case here: the changes you made looked substantial enough that they deserved judgement in their own right, rather than being quietly attributed to the original author.

In cases where you need to make a significant change to answer code that still preserves the essential intent of the author (which is how it appears to me, knowing VBA), the procedure is to **comment** with a summary of the necessary changes and allow enough time for the author (or others, perhaps) to hash out whether your changes are correct before suggesting an edit. Reviewers can't be expected to know all the technical details or be able to tell if a significant number of lines added to code is actually a significant addition, so the good ones will rely on comments by experts made on the post already. (The bad ones will either reject it out of hand or blindly accept it, depending on the phase of the moon.)

Answer (score -2):

Here is the list of occasions suggested by `Stack Overflow` for how to make edits.

```
to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
to add related resources or hyperlinks
```

If you try to modify the content of the original poster then it will be rejected for sure.

You may not want to steal the content from the previous posts, you can provide the reference to other answers and post the diff (improvement) by yourself in a meaningful way.

Comment: I definitely would agree with not stealing the content but, using a small snippet (correctly giving credit) to show where something needs to be inserted should be ok.

Answer (score -7):

The appropriate way of moving forward is, move on to the next question. The edit has been rejected, it doesn't matter if its because of the "dumbest" reason. It's has already been rejected, there's nothing more to it. You can either take it as a *"What a douche, my edit was right"* or as *"Well, I tried to help... OP's loss"* either way, there's no point in making a huge deal about it. There's plenty of questions on SO that need and will accept your edits OP. **On to the next question**